# Proof for showing convergence in distribution with characteristic function

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, characteristic-functions

I need help with a proof by using the characteristic function.
 To show : with
$$ X_n \rightarrow X $$ in distribution ,  follows that also
$$ aX_n + b \rightarrow aX +b $$ converges in distribution.
$a,b \in \mathbb{R} $

okay,..
so because of $ X_n \rightarrow X $ ,
it applies for the characteristic function, that  $ \phi_{X_n} (t) \rightarrow,  \phi_X (t) $  right?
I also know that $ \phi_{X1+....+X_n} = \phi_{X_1} * \phi_{X_2}*...*\phi_{X_n} $.

I feel like this is a very easy proof...but what else do i need?

I appreciate any help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi_{n}(t)=Ee^{itX_n}$ and $\phi_{X}(t)=Ee^{itX}$. Then
$$
E\exp(it(aX_{n}+b))=\exp(itb)\phi_{n}(at)
$$
and note that
$$
\exp(itb)\phi_{n}(at)\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to} \exp(itb)\phi_{X}(at)
$$
for all $t$ since $X_n\to X$ in distribution. But $\exp(itb)\phi_{X}(at)$ is the c.f of $aX+b$.